# How to find the graph of $e^{2x}$ and $\ln y$

Tags: graphing-functions

I'd like to know how find the graph I just only know how to draw the common function graph as circle or ellipse but I don't know how to draw.

For example 
 $e^{2x}$ and $\ln y$.

Note:the interval for $e^{2x}, \;[0,\ln 2].$
How can I determine $\ln 2$ on the graph?

It's better if somebody help me to find resource to learn more about graph -online please

Thanks all

Comment: Why's $e^2x$ tricky? Isn't it in the form of $f(x) = mx$?

Comment: I meant e^(2x) but the editor thought e^(2)x :)

Comment: I corrected the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $y = e^{2x} $ is a function: it takes values of $x$ as input, and outputs the function value $y = e^{2x}$.

[image]

Here, we have that the interval $[0, \ln 2]$ defines the domain of $x$, for the purposes of your graph.

$\ln 2 \in \mathbb R$ is a constant, and defines an endpoint of the domain in question.

Note that $y = e^{2x}$ at $x = \ln 2$ outputs $ e^{\large 2\cdot \ln 2} = e^{\large \ln(2^2)} = e^{\large \ln 4} = 4$.

So you can plot the "end points" of your graph: $(0, e^{2\cdot 0}) = (0, 1)$, and the point $(\underbrace{\ln 2}_{x}, \;\underbrace{e^{2\cdot \ln 2}}_{y}) = (\ln 2, 4)$.

Note that $\ln 2 \approx 
.6931$.

---

We also have the function $f(y) = \ln y$, and in this case, we have that the function depends on the input value of $y$, which are all real values greater than zero. So here, we consider the ordered pairs $(y, \ln y)$, and obtain the plot (blue graph):

[image]

---

For a handy on-line graphing resource, feel free to explore with [***Wolfram Alpha***](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20e%5E%7B2x%7D), which I used to obtain the graphs posted above, and also use as a calculator. It is quite powerful, for you purposes!

You'll also want to start developing some intuition on the shapes of the most important functions, two of which are $f(x) = e^x$ and $f(x) = \ln x$. The best way to develop such an intuition is through practice: graphing by hand, and graphing using a graphing calculator and/or an on-line resource! Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much you really help me :)

Comment: You're welcome!! My pleasure ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice graphs and all +1

Answer (score 1):

You should know the graph of $y=e^x$. 
Then, the graph of $y=e^{2x}$ is the 'shorten' graph of $y=e^x$ in the direction of the $x$ axis . You'll see the both graphs [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3De%5Ex+and+y%3De%5E%282x%29).

Also, note that $e^0=1, e^{2\ln 2}=4$, which means the graph of $y=e^{2x}$ passes the two points $(0,1),(\ln 2, 4).$ However, we don't know the exact value of $\ln 2\approx0.693.$ see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_e%202).

Comment: thank you, but why you didn't write e^(2ln2) not e^(ln2) thank you

Comment: because I set $x=\ln 2$ in $e^{2x}$.